# How to resolve docker name resolution failure?

Tags: docker-compose

Below is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
# Run tests in much the same way as circleci
# docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up
# TODO check aws versions

services:
  db:
    # image: circleci/postgres:11-alpine
    image: kotify/postgres-non-durable:11.2
    env_file: .env-test
    container_name: limetonic_db
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  redis:
    image: circleci/redis:6.2.1-alpine
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:89.0
    container_name: limetonic_selenium
    shm_size: '2gb'
    environment:
      TZ: "Australia/Sydney"
    ports: 
      - 4444:4444
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env-test
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
      - selenium
    command: bash -c "make ci.test"
```

The db, redis, selenium containers have DNS as 127.0.0.11 while test has 8.8.8.8. Now I am spinning a django server at `test:8000` but it does not come up with name resolution failure which I understand is coming from 8.8.8.8 DNS.

I have read many questions on SO but none of the solutions work. I have modified DOCKER_OPTS and changes dnsmasq etc. Now this problem occurs in stock ubuntu installation and any changes made does not work.

It does not matter what DNS is in docker `test` container it won't resolve `test`.

Note that db, selenium and redis can ping each other but obviously test cannot.

My `systemd-resolv` has DNS as 4.2.2.2 and 8.8.8.8 that is why test is not resolving. I understand that docker does not take 127.0.0.11 as DNS. However, if that is the case how other images can resolve with the local DNS? And even if I set DNS of test container to 127.0.0.11 it still does not resolve test?

Comment: What's setting the DNS server address?  (Normally Docker will supply it for you, and you don't show an option to override it.)  The Compose setup you show looks like it overrides the `command:` for the `test` container; is it actually starting the Django server?  From where are you calling `http://test:8000`?

Comment: systemd-resolve as I said no matter what DNS I set it won't resolve test. I have set 17.16.*, 127.0.* and so on. No matter what test will never resolve. I am checking test from inside test conttainer and also from other containers.

Comment: No it does not start the django server. The django server is started by fixture of pytest test cases.

Comment: Where does systemd come into the picture?  It tries to manage a huge amount of things including several network-related settings that Docker manages itself (and kernel-level settings that it will generally be prohibited from changing); can you run this stack without systemd involved?

Comment: The other option I have is to pass DNS in DOCKER_OPTS one set to 127.0.0.11 and another 8.8.8.8 but that does not resolve `test` either.